# Selecting only single rows from a number of single source-multiple values

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Source   | Values
------------------------
Tester   | Sample01
Tester   | AnotherSample
Tester   | Samples
Tester2  | Isitasample
Tester2  | sampledagain
Tester2  | testdata
Tester3  | approximation
Tester3  | <null>
```

and as a result I only want to have a single entry from each source, like:

```
Source   | Values
-----------------------
Tester   | Sample01
Tester2  | sampledagain
Tester3  | <null>
```

I have thought about distinct and join but I can only come up with solutions that filter out values alltogether. Same with unions. I am stumped.

Comment: If the data is different between records, then these are not duplicated entries. It seems you are not sharing all the relevant information. Is there a timestamp column?

Comment: Okay, then not duplicate but rather multiple values from the same source and I always want to just pick one value so I get the small sample table I provided.

Comment: Any value? Arbitrary value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let t = datatable (Source:string, Values:string)
[
     'Tester'  ,'Sample01'
    ,'Tester'  ,'AnotherSample'
    ,'Tester'  ,'Samples'
    ,'Tester2'  ,'Isitasample'
    ,'Tester2' ,'sampledagain'
    ,'Tester2' ,'testdata'
    ,'Tester3' ,'approximation'
    ,'Tester3' ,'<null>'
];
// Option 1
t
| summarize arg_max("", *) by Source
| project-away max_
```

| Source | Values |
| --- | --- |
| Tester | Sample01 |
| Tester2 | Isitasample |
| Tester3 | approximation |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA23QPQvCMBAG4D2/4nBJlYhfm1/g6OSguIjIaY8aSdKSXNGKP97UOij0stzxvAnkDDEwLCBFjudsCJJtXvoLTQN77TIFezQlhe/YFQcBdckdBSYvAZTcoi0MDUfyQ%20qXVi7nK/km0eINhH8Zf2gdNGNouRhZyQZSzFC7FubY1l/6p0lNWBQ%20f2iLrHPX4nNXGrOU4jgTgwFsijoGI8HiBaG0Fr1%20EqDPThYfSaejoNeFcwXN1mIovn6jC/fxjhXEzOkNFXzlAGMBAAA=)